# Nginx - Only enable SSL if SSL Certificates Exist

Tags: ssl, nginx, https

I have an issue wherein I am building an nginx reverse proxy for directing to multiple microservices at different url paths.

The system is entirely docker based and as a result the same environment is used for development and production. This has caused an issue for me when installing SSL as the SSL certs will only be available in production so when I configure NGINX with SSL the development environment no longer works as the ssl certs are not present.

Here is the relevant part of my conf file -

```
server {
 listen 80;
 listen 443 default_server ssl;

 server_name          atvcap.server.com;
 ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/certs/atvcap_cabundle.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/certs/atvcap.key;
 ...
}
```

But this throws the following when running my application in development mode -

> nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/nginx/certs/atvcap_cabundle.crt") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/nginx/certs/atvcap_cabundle.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)

Is it possible to only turn on SSL if the "/etc/nginx/certs/atvcap_cabundle.crt" is available?

I had tried something like the following -

```
if (-f /etc/nginx/certs/atvcap_cabundle.crt) {
  ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/certs/atvcap_cabundle.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/certs/atvcap.key;
}
```

But that threw the following error -

> nginx: [emerg] "ssl_certificate" directive is not allowed here in
>   /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:7

Any one have any ideas on how to achieve something like this?

Thanks

Comment: As a temporary workaround for now I've just created two nginx.conf files - one for dev and one for production. The dev one overwrites the production mode when we're in dev mode. Ideally I don't want to have 2 files doing almost the same thing.

Comment: I am looking for the same solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create an additional file **ssl.conf** and put here ssl configs:

```
ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/certs/atvcap_cabundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/certs/atvcap.key;
```

Then include from the main config:

```
server_name          atvcap.server.com;

include /somepath/ssl.conf*;
```

Make sure to include * symbol - this will not break when the file does not exist at development mode.

Comment: Regardless of this technique which helps to overcome to solve this problem, but is there any way to enable ssl file if there is appropriate `.crt` file?

Comment: How would this help? There's no if condition so it will be included anyways?

Answer (score 5):

The answer of @super_p is correct. But to answer to @AbdolHosein comment I add my answer here if it's not clear.

You need to include your `ssl_certificate` directive in the included file.

```
# sample nginx config
http {
    server {
        listen 80 deferred;
        server_name _;

        include /ssl/ssl.conf*;

        client_body_timeout 5s;
        client_header_timeout 5s;

        root /code;
    }
}
```

Then in your `/ssl/ssl.conf` you can do whatever you want, such as enabling HTTPS:

```
# this is the /ssl/ssl.conf file
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

ssl_certificate /ssl/cert.cer;
ssl_certificate_key /ssl/key.key;
ssl_session_timeout 1d;
ssl_session_cache shared:MozSSL:10m;
ssl_session_tickets off;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
```

The trick is that we don't look if the certificate exists but we check if the `/ssl/ssl.conf` exists. This is thanks to the `*` in the `include /ssl/ssl.conf*;` directory as stated by @super_p

Comment: I opened an issue: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/2244